# DC.js Heatmaps color scale per row

Tags: dc.js

I have a heatmap and want to individually set the color scheme for every row. Is that possible? With the following code i can create a working heatmap but the color is the same for all rows.

```
fooHeatmap = dc.heatMap("#fooHeatmap")
                .width(width)
                .height(height)
                .dimension(fooDim)
                .group(fooGroup)
                .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
                .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
                .colorAccessor(function(d) { return d.value; })
                .colors(d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0,1, fooGroup.top(1)[0].value])
                    .range(["#bbb","#D0DDFF","blue"]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dc.js only uses one color scale per chart, but you may be able to combine `d.key[1]` into the color accessor in order to create disjoint color spaces, and specify multiple domain values for the color scale in order to create multiple color ranges.

This is called a [polylinear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales%23linear_domain).

E.g. if `d.value` ranges between 0.0 and 1.0, and `.d.key[1]` is 0,1,2,3...:

```
 .colorAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]*2 + d.value; })
 .colors(d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5...])
     .range([color0,color1,color2,color3,color4,color5...]))
```

Now `colorAccessor` will return values between 0.0-1.0, 2.0-3.0, 4.0-5.0,... and the linear scale will map them between color0-color1, color2-color3, color4-color5...

It is kind of tricky and you'd have to know all the row values to begin with.

Comment: It worked quite well but i had to normalize my values

Comment: Awesome! Yes it is an annoying way to go about things. I think it would be pretty tough to change the chart to accept multiple scales, so this may be the best solution. I guess some helper could be devised to do the work of normalizing and offsetting the values...